# Не могу сохранить файл Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, response

```
   photo = 'http://x.x.x.x:80/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/101/picture?snapShotImageType=JPEG'
           h.add_credentials(cuser, cpass)
           response, content = h.request(photo)
           with open(saves, 'w+') as f:
               f.write(content)
```

> ```
>  /home/pi/html/image.jpg
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "CreateFoto.py", line 62, in <module>
>         with open(saves, 'w+') as f:
>     PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/......./image.jpg'
> ```

К папке конечно же доступ есть.

Answer (score 0):

В папке уже был файл, и по каким-то причинам не мог перезаписаться. Удалил, все заработало.